How to map expectation values to continuous values
I am attempting to do a variational quantum algorithm where the circuit is parameterized with ${\theta}$ and then I calculate the expectation value of the qubit, plug it in a cost function and then an optimizer optimizes ${\theta}$ to minimize the cost function.
The output of the circuit (expectation value) should be passed to the cost function and my cost function is expecting a continuous variable. I know that expectation values can only be between -1 and 1 for PauliZ observable.
My question is how to convert this expectation value to this continuous variable that my cost function needs given that there is not a specific bound to the values?

Please add detail on the cost function. How does the optimiser use the function? What are domain and co-domain.

Well, one thing is that if you are trying to optimize for the function
$$f(\theta) := \langle \psi| \hat{U}_{\theta}^{\dagger} \hat{A}\hat{U}_{\theta}| \psi\rangle$$
where $\hat{A}$ is some observible and $\hat{U}_{\theta}$ is the net unitary that your circuit is implementing (which depends on the parameter $\theta$), then your optimizer usually needs the gradient $\nabla_{\theta}f(\theta)$. If so, you can get the value of that gradient either using numerical differentiation or sometimes exactly (in a sense) by using the parameter-shift rule (See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11184) where you run a circuit twice for two different values of the parameter and take a suitable difference.
However, all these quantities are referring to an expectation value, and the only way you can get (an estimate of) that from an actual quantum device is by running the circuit multiple times (i.e., for multiple shots) and taking the empirical average of the outcome. It is then up to you to design protocols to worry about how much averaging needs to be done to feed useful information to the optimizer (perhaps you only care about your gradients being stochastically correct, for instance).

The problem is that your circuit outcome has discrete domain -- i.e. any combination of bits.
You can generate one variable from the outcome. It won't be continuous though.
A trivial solution is to take the basis-10 number associated to the bit-string in outcome. This is not continuous, but it is a single variable.
Try to define a procedure -- e.g. hash -- that maps bit strings to a (discrete) subset of your cost function.
If you necessarily need >1 continuous variables (extracted from a single run of the ansatz), you will have to do more than this; take sub-strings from the measurements and combine them to generate more than one variable. E.g. use the power-set and then conclude with an hash map (make sure you don't create repetitions).
P.S. if this is not the answer you are looking for, consider to add further details to the question.
